# Form submit button not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to implement a voting system, but I'm having some trouble, I've tried creating a form with a hidden field:

```
       <% form_for :vote, url: votes_path do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :rating, value: '1' %></td>
          <%= form_submit_button("vote 1") %>
       <% end %>
```

But when I run that the submit button does not appear, I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`form_for` generates `<FORM>` tag, so you need to include its output with `<%=`:

```
<%= form_for :vote, url: votes_path do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
   <%= form_for :vote, url: votes_path do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :rating, value: '1' %></td>
      <%= form_submit_button("vote 1") %>
   <% end %>
```

`=` is usually shows the form in view page, if you remove it then any input tag will not be displayed.